# TSQL Row_Number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, window-functions

This question has been covered similarly before BUT I'm struggling.

I need to find top N sales based on customer buying patterns..

ideally this needs to be top N by customer by Month Period by Year but for now i'm just looking at top N over the whole DB.

My query looks like:

```
-- QUERY TO SHOW TOP 2 CUSTOMER INVOICES BY CUSTOMER BY MONTH

SELECT
    bill_to_code,
    INVOICE_NUMBER,
    SUM( INVOICE_AMOUNT_CORP ) AS 'SALES',
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY bill_to_code ORDER BY SUM( INVOICE_AMOUNT_CORP ) DESC ) AS 'Row'
FROM
    FACT_OM_INVOICE
    JOIN dim_customer_bill_to ON FACT_OM_INVOICE.dim_customer_bill_to_key = dim_customer_bill_to.dim_customer_bill_to_key
--WHERE
--    'ROW' < 2
GROUP BY
    invoice_number,
    Dim_customer_bill_to.bill_to_code
```

I can't understand the solutions given to restrict Row to =< N.

Please help.

Comment: Your query doesn't look far off.  Row number will number the records in each group according to an order.  You can then restrict to the first two records from each group.

Comment: You don't need `ROW_NUMBER`, just do `SELECT TOP 2` with a top-level `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
-- QUERY TO SHOW TOP 2 CUSTOMER INVOICES BY CUSTOMER BY MONTH
;WITH Top2Customers
AS
(
SELECT
    bill_to_code,
    INVOICE_NUMBER,
    SUM( INVOICE_AMOUNT_CORP ) AS 'SALES',
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY bill_to_code ORDER BY SUM( INVOICE_AMOUNT_CORP ) DESC ) 
    AS 'RowNumber'
FROM
    FACT_OM_INVOICE
    JOIN dim_customer_bill_to ON FACT_OM_INVOICE.dim_customer_bill_to_key = dim_customer_bill_to.dim_customer_bill_to_key
GROUP BY
    invoice_number,
    Dim_customer_bill_to.bill_to_code
)
SELECT * FROM Top2Customers WHERE RowNumber < 3
```

Comment: Thanks Shiva! This one works. Can you explain the 'with top2customers as' part. Is this declaring a temp table?

Comment: Cool.  Yes, the `WITH top2customers AS` is like a temp table, but more powerful. It's called a CTE - Common Table Expression. See this for more info and examples: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your select into another to use the value produced by row_number()

```sql
select * from (
SELECT
    bill_to_code,
    INVOICE_NUMBER,
    SUM( INVOICE_AMOUNT_CORP ) AS SALES,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY bill_to_code ORDER BY SUM( INVOICE_AMOUNT_CORP ) DESC ) AS RowNo
FROM
    FACT_OM_INVOICE
    JOIN dim_customer_bill_to ON FACT_OM_INVOICE.dim_customer_bill_to_key = dim_customer_bill_to.dim_customer_bill_to_key
--WHERE
--    'ROW' < 2
GROUP BY
    invoice_number,
    Dim_customer_bill_to.bill_to_code
) base where RowNo < 2
```

Comment: Thanks Jan but this one is still coming up with the dreaded 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'row' to data type int.' error.

Comment: I've changed column names from your sample, try now.